# Bounding box volume of an STL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3d

I am trying to find bounding box volume of an STL file using the following code. For most of the files it is working fine but for files it gives strange result, means very high X, Y and Z values. Please help me to fix it.

```
enter code here

    float length, breadth, height;
            float minx = 0, maxx = 0,
            miny=0, maxy=0,
            minz=0, maxz=0;


     public double signedVolumeOfTriangle(float[] p1, float[] p2, float[] p3)
    {
        double v321 = p3[0] * p2[1] * p1[2];
        double v231 = p2[0] * p3[1] * p1[2];
        double v312 = p3[0] * p1[1] * p2[2];
        double v132 = p1[0] * p3[1] * p2[2];
        double v213 = p2[0] * p1[1] * p3[2];
        double v123 = p1[0] * p2[1] * p3[2];
        double vol = (1.0 / 6.0) * (-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123);


        if (Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[0], p2[0]), p3[0]) < minx)
        {
            minx = Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[0], p2[0]), p3[0]);
        }
        else if (Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[0], p2[0]), p3[0]) > maxx)
        {
            maxx = Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[0], p2[0]), p3[0]);
        }


        if (Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[1], p2[1]), p3[1]) < miny)
        {
            miny = Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[1], p2[1]), p3[1]);
        }
        else if (Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[1], p2[1]), p3[1]) > maxy)
        {
            maxy = Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[1], p2[1]), p3[1]);
        }

        if (Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[2], p2[2]), p3[2]) < minz)
        {
            minz = Math.Min(Math.Min(p1[2], p2[2]), p3[2]);
        }
        else if (Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[2], p2[2]), p3[2]) > maxz)
        {
            maxz = Math.Max(Math.Max(p1[2], p2[2]), p3[2]);
        }

        return vol;
    }

    public float[] getBoundingBox()
    {
        length = maxx - minx;
        breadth = maxy - miny;
        height = maxz - minz;
        return new float[] { length, breadth, height };
    }
```

Thanks

ayha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all the `else`.
After computing the min you still need to compute the max.

Also, `getBoundingBox` only returns the dimension `{ length, breadth, height }` of the aabb. Its position relative to `(minx, miny, minz)` is lost.

Finally, make sure your global variables are initialized correctly for instance: `minx=+INFINITY` and `maxx=-INFINITY`, same for `y` and `z`.

Comment: After removing the all the "else", the result is same.

Comment: @ayha the 'else' is definitely an error. Other than that how do you initialize your globals minx maxx miny maxy minz maxz?

Comment: you should edit your question rather than sending code as comments

Comment: you can't set the min and max to zero

Comment: minx=+INFINITY and maxx=-INFINITY same for y and z. INFINITY is a very large constant.

Comment: @ayha for instance if minx==0 and your object's actual minimum x is 20 then minx won't be updated

Comment: what is change is needed in getBoundingBox?

Comment: @ayha you need to correctly initialize your global variables, remove the else in the minmax computation and finally inroder to use the aabb you still need minx miny and minz in addition to length, breadth and height

Comment: After removing all "else" and initializing the global variables I get the correct dimensions. How can I make the last change in the getBoundingBox()?

Comment: just use min/max x,y,z directly as they completely define the bounding box

Comment: once you initialize and fix the 'else', min/max x,y,z will be correct. How do you use them (how do you use the bounding box)?